# Doctest and relative imports

Tags: python, doctest

I'm having trouble using doctest with relative imports.  The simple solution is just to get rid of the relative imports.  Are there any others?

Say I have a package called example containing 2 files:

**`example/__init__.py`**

```
"""
This package is entirely useless.
>>> arnold = Aardvark()
>>> arnold.talk()
I am an aardvark.
"""

from .A import Aardvark

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

**example/A.py**

```
class Aardvark(object):
    def talk(self):
        print("I am an aardvark.")
```

If I now attempt

```
python example/__init__.py
```

then I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .A import Aardvark
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: I would get rid of the relative imports, many Python style guides strongly discourage them, most forbid them.

Comment: @JasonScheirer Are there any examples for this discouragement? In projects like `numpy` these are very common.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create another file `my_doctest_runner.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    import example
    doctest.testmod(example)
```

Execute `my_doctest_runner.py` to run doctests in `example/__init__.py`:

```
$ python2.7 my_doctest_runner.py
**********************************************************************
File "/tmp/example/__init__.py", line 4, in example
Failed example:
    arnold.talk()
Expected:
    I am an aaardvark.
Got:
    I am an aardvark.
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in example
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In the end I've ended up changing the relative import to an absolute one, (from example.A import Aadvark) based on Jason Scheirer's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Pytest's [`--doctest-modules`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/doctest.html) flag takes care of relative imports:

```bash
$ ls example/
A.py  __init__.py
$ pytest --doctest-modules example
==================== test session starts ====================
...

example/__init__.py .                                 [100%]

===================== 1 passed in 0.03s =====================
```

Comment: Just note that this won't work well with relative imports in namespace packages, so you might need to place an empty `__init__.py` if you currently have none.

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
from A import Aardvark
```

Comment: well, I am afraid this breaks python 3 compatibility.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score -1):

As of pytest 6.0.0, `importlib` is a valid [import mode](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html). Using that solved the problem for me.

```bash
pytest --import-mode=importlib
```